# Style of my Cognito Form does not match that for the rest of my website

Tags: cognito-forms

I inserted a Cognito form into my website but the style (none of the options) does not match the rest of the website.

How can I override the style to match my site?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Are you embedding your form onto a WordPress site? 

Have you tried the Publish page to style your form?

Could you provide a link to your website so that we may take a look at how your styles are interacting with ours?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample css that fully customizes the look and feel of the fields and validation.  It isn't pretty, but illustrates how to accomplish this:

```
.cognito #c-forms-form{ background:#aed136; color:#698215; font-family:'Open Sans'; overflow:hidden; padding-right:3em; }
.cognito .c-section,.cognito .c-field:nth-child(1){ margin-top:0; padding-top:0; }
.cognito .c-forms-heading{ display:none; }
.cognito .c-label,.cognito .c-editor,.cognito .c-action,.cognito .c-validation,.cognito .c-forms-thankyou-message{ margin:0; padding:0 4px!important; }
.cognito #c-forms-form label{ color:#FFF; }
.cognito .c-label{ margin-bottom:.3em; }
.cognito .c-editor{ margin-bottom:.2em; }
.cognito #c-submit-button{ background:#9fc226; border:0; float:none; font-family:'Open Sans'; font-size:1.5em; font-weight:900; margin:0; outline:0; padding:.4em; width:5em; }
.cognito #c-submit-button:hover{ background:#698215; }
.cognito .c-editor textarea{ height:5em; resize:none; }
.cognito .c-editor input[type=text],.cognito .c-editor textarea{ border:0; box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0 2px #eaeaea, 4px 4px 0 0 #a6c92f; color:#d85527; font-family:'Open Sans'; font-weight:500; padding:.6em; }
.cognito .c-editor input[type=text]:focus,.cognito .c-editor textarea:focus{ background:#fff5f1; box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0 2px #ffe4db, 4px 4px 0 0 #a6c92f; outline:none; }
.cognito .c-validation{ background:#d85527; border-radius:0; font-size:.8em; left:0; margin-top:-.4em; position:absolute; }
.cognito .c-validation:after{ border:solid transparent; border-bottom-color:#d85527; border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); border-width:7px; bottom:100%; content:" "; height:0; left:15px; margin-left:-7px; pointer-events:none; position:absolute; width:0; }
.cognito .c-field-required{ display:none; }
```

As an example of how to use this, I created a simple HTML document with the embed code for my form, and added a `<style>` element to the `<head>` tag with the above code.

edit: I'm a member of the Cognito team

Answer (score -2):

See this example could help you. 
https://codepen.io/hardo91/full/OrMMBZ

Comment: Could you summarize what's at the link in the body of your post, please?